# What are the laws of physics of the Multiverse ? What is the multiversal constant?

Tags: multiverse

What are the laws of physics outside our Universe ? Can a Multiverse constant exist ? And what is the Multiverse constant if it exists ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A multiverse is highly speculative. In multiverse theories, fundamental constants such as the total number of dimensions, the speed of light, Planck’s constant, and the tension in a string are the same across universes, but “effective field theory” quantities such as the mass of the electron or the fine structure constant can be different in different universes. Other universes might not even have any effective fields that behave like electron fields or electromagnetic fields. The specific fields effectively present in a particular universe, and the interactions between them, might depend on the geometric details of how higher dimensions (typically six of them) compactified (or didn’t) in that universe.